# Do the following make use of some design patterns?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Given

```
class ClassA
{
    void MethodA(ClassB ObjB) {...}
}
```

do the following make use of some design patterns:

```
class ClassC: ClassB
{
    void MethodC(ClassA ObjA) {ObjA.MethodA(this);}
}
```

and

```
class ClassD
{   
    ClassB _objB;
    void MethodC(ClassA ObjA) {ObjA.MethodA(this._objB);}
}
```

?

For example

```
Class MyData
{
    int data;
    void Write(BinaryWriter writer){writer.Write(data);};
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why do you ask, please give some background or is it just a question to increase  your points.

Comment: Is there any point to this code  seams to be completely redundant? I think you can name it what ever you want as long as you make a good case to this being useful

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thanks. Just added.

Comment: @Tim - Not quite there yet. If I copy and paste your code it does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a light version of the Visitor design pattern:[image]

```
  using System;
  using System.Text;

  interface IExpressionVisitor
  {
    void Visit(Literal literal);
    void Visit(Addition addition);
  }

  interface IExpression
  {
    void Accept(IExpressionVisitor visitor);
  }

  class Literal : IExpression
  {
    internal double Value { get; set; }

    public Literal(double value)
    {
      this.Value = value;
    }
    public void Accept(IExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
      visitor.Visit(this);
    }
  }
```

extracted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: Thanks. how is it a visitor pattern?

Comment: If you look the method Accept, it looks like the MethodA